# previous and next id from a table with mysql query

Tags: mysql

I have a query which lists all the contacts on one page. If I select one contact it will display details of that contact. On that page I want to keep one prev and next button so that user can go back and forth within the contacts which were listed on the first page.
If I get the next and previous id available for written query I can get the results as expected. Is it possible to do?

Comment: I haven't started anything on this problem. I just posted this question to get some better ideas.

Comment: I'd just store the results from the first page/query, and then handle the pagination at the application level - with some php or javascript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this(we assume that your current id is 4):

-for next

```
select * from foo where id = (select min(id) from foo where id > 4)
```

-for previous

```
select * from foo where id = (select max(id) from foo where id < 4)
```

Comment: That's great. But I have lot of filters with my query and around 60000 of contacts. Is there any other feasible way to do it. Because I need to run this query with lots of filters again and again on all the pages. Is there any way so I can associate the prev and next id with each contacts.

Comment: Thank you so much..  I think it will work for me. I will try with this.